# Plotting multiple time series plots using median data in R

Tags: r, plot, timeserieschart

Im just beginning to learn R so this might be redundant so I apologize. I am wanting to make this attach excel graph in R. My data includes daily water level reading for a reservoir from 1951 to 2016. I need the data broken into three series (1951 to 2013, 2014 to 2015, and 2016). I would like to plot the median values for these series per calendar day. And I would like to remove febuary 29 from the median values. Here is a link to my data:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u1Whfp6VHXkZgrC0sVn_mT9XiVxszMhqlAszjZXzM1E/edit?usp=sharing

Here is what I have so far:

```
LL <- read.csv("BSLL.csv")
str(LL)
LLpre <- filter(LL, year > "1952" & year <"2014") 
headtail(LLpre, n=3)
medianLLpre = ddply(LLpre, .(month, day), summarise, level = median(level),   na.rm = FALSE)
LLpost <- filter(LL, year > "2013" & year < "2016")
headtail(LLpost, n=3)
medianLLpost = ddply(LLpost, .(month, day), summarise, level = median(level), na.rm = FALSE)
LL2016 <- filter(LL, year == "2016")
headtail(LL2016, n=3)
medianLL2016 = ddply(LL2016, .(month, day), summarise, level = median(level), na.rm = FALSE)
```

[Excel Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZTF5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
Data <- fread("BSLL - BSLL.csv")
```

Create temporary time interval categories 1=1951 to 2013,2=2014 to 2015, and 3=2016

```
Data[,Categories:=ifelse(as.numeric(year)<2014,1,
                         ifelse(as.numeric(year)<2016,2,3))]
```

Create temporary data with no feb 29th

```
Temp.Data <- Data[!month==2][!day==29]
```

Compute the median by categories and plot.

```
Medians <- Temp.Data[,median(as.numeric(level)),by=.(month,Categories)]
plot(x=Medians[,month], y=Medians[,V1],type="n", xlab="", ylab="", 
     xaxt="n", yaxt="n", bty="l")
axis(2, tick=TRUE, labels=FALSE)
axis(2, tick=FALSE, labels=TRUE, line=-0.5)
axis(1, tick=TRUE, labels=FALSE)
axis(1, tick=FALSE, labels=TRUE, line=-0.5)
lines(x=Medians[Categories==1][,month],
      y=Medians[Categories==1][,V1],type="l",lwd=1,col="red")
lines(x=Medians[Categories==2][,month],
      y=Medians[Categories==2][,V1],type="l",lwd=1,col="green")
lines(x=Medians[Categories==3][,month],
      y=Medians[Categories==3][,V1],type="l",lwd=1,col="blue")
legend('topright','groups',
       legend=c("1951 to 2013","2014 to 2015","2016"), bty="n",lty=c(1,1),
       col=c("red","green","blue"))
```

How's this? You can tinker with the details of the plot (sizes, positions, colours, labels, etc.. yourself)

P.S in future its not a good idea to release your full data set publicly. Contributors here just need an example of your data to work with and test

Comment: Thank you for the advice about sharing data.

Comment: Did you try the script in my answer? Did they give you what you needed? if so then please click the check mark so this question can be considered closed.

Comment: I was looking to develop line graphs instead of bar plots over a calendar year. I attached an excel plot to provide a better explanation of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ah okay so you want monthly medians for years classified as indicated. No problemo, ill get back to you in a few

Comment: Adjusted script as requested. If this is what you needed please click the check mark beside the answer so that this question can be considered closed